# Why abstract does not work for interface implicit methods?

Tags: java, interface, abstract, jls

While reading [JLS Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.2) for Interfaces I came across following phrase:

> If an interface has no direct superinterfaces, then the interface
>   implicitly declares a public abstract member method m with signature
>   s, return type r, and throws clause t corresponding to each public
>   instance method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t
>   declared in Object, unless a method with the same signature, same
>   return type, and a compatible throws clause is explicitly declared by
>   the interface.

So My question is when we implement an interface why we are not forced to override implicit methods which are declared in `Object` class even though they are implicitly defined as abstract in Interface.
Hope I put myself correctly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All classes implicitly `extend Object`, either directly or through some chain of superclasses. Thus, you don't have to explicitly override the implicit methods declared in an interface because you inherited the implementations from `Object`.

Comment: Ahh!! Missed this..Btw Thanks..:)

Answer (score 0):

The point of an interface is to force you to implement some method. The reason everything extends Object is that we want to have some way of dealing with all classes independent of implementation. There is no reason that each class should implement something like getClass(), because the behaviour is always going to be the same.